Cannot install "Rsafd" library in R
Hi I'm learning from this textbook: Statistical Analysis of Financial Data in R for a while. The author introduced "Rsafd" library to use in the textbook.
I've tried these lines of code but fail to compile.

library(Rsafd)

Error in library(Rsafd) : there is no package called ‘Rsafd’
try to install

install.packages("Rsafd", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")

it returns
... 

xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
Warning in system(paste(MAKE, p1(paste("-f", shQuote(makefiles))), "compilers"),  :
  running command 'make -f 'Makevars' -f '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/etc/Makeconf' -f '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/share/make/shlib.mk' compilers' had status 1
sh: --version: command not found
sh: --version: command not found
Warning in system2("xcrun", "--show-sdk-path", TRUE, TRUE) :
  running command ''xcrun' --show-sdk-path 2>&1' had status 1
using SDK: ‘NA’

...

I search for some doc. only this website has info. : https://rdrr.io/rforge/Rsafd/
but can't install from that either.
Learning financial stat analysis is a huge inspiration for me. Without actual coding I can't read on the next chapters. Please help. Thanks in advance.

failed installation of software problems are not quantitative finance

I suppose that it is the package described here: https://carmona.princeton.edu/statistical-analysis ? This is more of an R question, and so there might be more-appropriate forums such as R SIG Finance. But since the code belongs to a finance textbook: The package code on R-Forge is here: https://r-forge.r-project.org/R/?group_id=592 Have you tried to contact the original author (René Carmona) or the most recent maintainer (Kurt Hornik)?
